# What is the difference between randomUUID and GraphAware UUID in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, uuid

I am currently using *GraphAware UUID Library* to generate UUID in neo4j, later I found out that it has a `randomUUID()` function to generate UUID, which one should be used?, will `randomUUID()` create unique id on server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both call `java.util.UUID#randomUUID()`, that's where the similarity between them ends.

The built-in Cypher's `randomUUID()` is a function, which you have to call manually in each cypher query where you want to assign a UUID.

The `neo4j-uuid` module is a set of extensions to Neo4j, which allow you to transparently assign UUID (or other types of ids - depending on configured id generator) to nodes and relationships, ensures the ids can't be changed or deleted. It also maintains an explicit index for the nodes / relationships. See the readme for the [full feature](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid) set.

If your use case is simply to assign a uuid to (some) nodes or relationships then use the built in function. If you can take advantage of the other features of the neo4j-uuid module - use that.

Answer (score 1):

For manual use cases, creating the UUID yourself in a Cypher query, they're functionally identical (GraphAware implemented this first I think, we got to it later). Yes the ids will be created on the server and will be unique, both

I believe GraphAware's UUID module covers more than just this, doing automatic assigning of UUIDs to newly created nodes and relationships and extra validation on top of that.

Comment: so which one do you recommend? cause GraphAware doesn't return the UUID immediately after creation. @InverseFalcon

Comment: Again it depends upon what you need. Neo4j's uuid function is all manual, it's on you to call it when you set properties as you create graph elements (or to create a trigger for this). It's up to you what better meets your requirements.